# In the Dirac equation, do $\alpha$ and $p$ commute?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, dirac-equation

The Dirac Hamiltonian is given as $H = \vec \alpha·\vec pc + \beta mc^2$ , Do the alpha and beta operators commute with the momentum operator? If yes then how?

Comment: Have you writed down the full equation using matrices? It should become clear when you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they do. All three of the $\alpha$ matrices, as well as the beta matrix, are operators on the 'internal' degree of freedom of the electron (that is, its spin and the electron-positron distinction), while the momentum operator operates on its spatial degree of freedom. These are independent degrees of freedom, and operators on their different sectors of Hilbert space always commute.

Comment: Late to ask, but does that mean $\alpha$ matrices commute with the position operator too?

Comment: Yes, it does mean that.