# Commutation of alpha dirac matrix

Tags: homework-and-exercises, commutator, dirac-matrices

I want to calculate the commutation of $[\hat{x},\vec{\alpha}\;\vec{p}]$. This boils down to $$[\hat{x},\vec{\alpha}\;\vec{p}] = i\hbar\hat{\alpha_x}+\left[\hat{x},\hat{\alpha_x}\right]\hat{p_x} +\left[\hat{x},\hat{\alpha_y}\right]\hat{p_y} +\left[\hat{x},\hat{\alpha_z}\right]\hat{p_z}$$

My problem is calculating $[\hat{x},\hat{\alpha_x}]$, $[\hat{x},\hat{\alpha_y}]$ and $[\hat{x},\hat{\alpha_z}]$. Are they just zero? If so why?

Also is there a way I can represent $\hat{x}$ explicitly so that I can multiply it with $\hat{\alpha}$?

$$\hat{\pmb{\alpha}} = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & \pmb{\sigma} \\
    \pmb{\sigma} & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Where $\pmb{\sigma}$ the Pauli matrices.

Edit(Answer):
Since the matrices are arrays of numbers they do commute with $\hat{x}$ hence $[\hat{x},\vec{\alpha}\;\vec{p}] = i\hbar\hat{\alpha_x}$

Comment: Dirac matrices, Pauli matrices, etc... are arrays of *numbers*, not operators, so they all commute with Hilbert space operators.

Comment: Oh, so that would actually make them zero. Yeah that makes sense. Just a follow up question: If we consider $\frac{\partial{<\hat{x}>}}{\partial{t}} = -\frac{ic}{\hbar}<[\bar{x},\vec{\alpha}\;\vec{p}]>$ what physical interpretation does $\alpha$ take?

Comment: possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/476458/84967, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/104241/84967

Comment: Velocity? Is this part of your homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special thanks to Cosmas Zachos!

Since the matrices are arrays of numbers they do commute with $\hat{x}$. Furthermore we have $$\frac{\partial{<\hat{x}>}}{\partial{t}} = -\frac{ic}{\hbar}<\left[\hat{x},\vec{\alpha}\;\vec{p}\right]>$$

Now $\left[ \hat{x},\vec{\alpha}\;\vec{p}\right] = \vec{\alpha}[\hat{x},\vec{p}] + [\hat{x},\vec{\alpha}]\vec{p} = i\hbar\hat{\alpha_x}$ hence $$\frac{\partial{<\hat{x}>}}{\partial{t}} = -\frac{ic}{\hbar}<i\hbar\hat{\alpha_x}> = c\hat{\alpha_x}$$
This means we can classically interpret $\pmb{\vec{\alpha}}$ as the velocity.